# Python not found when trying to execute git-clang-format on Windows

Tags: python, windows, git, clang-format

I am trying to set up `git-clang-format` on Windows 10. I have following programs installed:

- git
- python 3.11.5
- LLVM 16.0.4 (which includes `clang-format` and `git-clang-format`)

Both python executable and LLVM's bin folder (containing `clang-format` executable and `git-clang-format` python script) are in the path. I can run the following commands without any issue

```
$ git --version
git version 2.42.0.windows.2

$ python --version
Python 3.11.5

$ clang-format --version
clang-format version 16.0.4
```

But for some reason, this command doesn't work

```
$ git clang-format -h
Python not found. Run without argument [...]
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Where do you type these commands?

Comment: I tried both Windows terminal and PowerShell

Comment: Can `python3` or `/usr/bin/env python3` run successfully?

Comment: @ElpieKay A simple script (hello world) works with `py hellow_world.py` and `python hellow_world.py` but `python3 hello_world.py` doesn't and outputs me the same error message as in my question. Do you think it could be a missing alias ? (running on Windows and not Linux btw).

Comment: @Vincent I think so. The shebang in `git-clang-format` is `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.  You could either change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python` or add a `python3` alias.

Comment: @ElpieKay Nice catch ! Changing the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python` and `git clang-format -h` works like a charm. It seems `python3` isn't a standard alias on Windows and users have to set it up manually. Thanks a lot for your help :) I'll write the answer in case someone else faces the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `git-clang-format` script, there is a shebang at the beginning of the file (`#!/usr/bin/env python3`) that tells the shell how to execute it.

> To learn more about shebangs, follow [this link](https://linuxhint.com/python-shebang/).

This shebang calls `python3` command. Unfortunately, Python installer for Windows only creates `py` and `python` commands, but not `python3`. So the shell can't find the interpreter, even though Python is correclty installed on the OS, thus returning the error message `Python not found. Run without argument [...]`.

There are 2 options to fix it (each is a working solution) :

1. *(preferred option)* Create an alias for `python3` that redirects to `python`. This can be done by going to the Python install directory and creating a shortcut `python3.exe` pointing to `python.exe`. Other methods are described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1576801).
2. Change `git-clang-format` shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python` (not advised as other processes might depend on this shebang, modify it might have unknown side effects).